# How can I remove parent path when importing a package from same monorepo?

Tags: node.js, lerna, nx-monorepo

I have a nodejs project which uses `nx` to manage multiple packages, the structure is:

```
packages/my-proj1/src/*.ts
packages/my-proj2/src/*.ts
...
```

the `my-prod2` has dependency on `my-proj1`, so in the package.json under `my-proj2`, it has dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-proj1": "*",
}
```

in the code of `my-proj2`, it imports files from `my-proj1` like:

```
import { ... } from 'my-proj1/src`
```

as you can see, it has to put `src` on the import statement. How can I make it work by removing the `src` folder from the import statement in `my-proj2`?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `tsconfig.base.json` file in the root of the monorepo where these paths are setup.

All you have to is change the `my-proj1` path to include the `src` directory.

```
paths: {
  "my-proj1": "path/to/my-proj1/src"
}
```

Though it's usually recommended to have a single file that exports everything from a project, and you'd then reference just that file:

```
// path/to/my-proj1/src/index.ts

export * from 'lib/somefile'
export * from 'lib/otherfile'
```

Then on the `tasconfig.base.json`:

```
paths: {
  "my-proj1": "path/to/my-proj1/src/index.ts"
}
```

Comment: I can put the tsconfig to root level and rename it as `tsconfig.base.json`, but it seems the tcs doesn't use the `paths` field.  Do I need to define `paths` in both `tsconfig.base.json` and `tsconfig.json` under each package folder?